# Put data in one line In csv file

Tags: java, export-to-csv

I'm trying to write xml data into csv file. Everything is working fine except when data's length is too long then its write the data in new line.e.g if address is too long then its going to next line and then write data.

```
public class ExportToCSV {

public static final String LINE_BREAK = "\n";
List<Line> lines = new ArrayList<Line>();
public static void main(String argv[]) {

    try {   File fXmlFile = new File("C:/Users/Master/Desktop/demo_jar/Eff_SOR.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("record");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        List< Map<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String,String>>();

        for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
             Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
             Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
             if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                   Element eElement = (Element) nNode; 

                   map.put("Address", eElement.getElementsByTagName("address_").item(0).getTextContent());                                 
                   map.put("Price1", eElement.getElementsByTagName("price1").item(0).getTextContent());                  
                   map.put("Base_qty1", eElement.getElementsByTagName("base_qty1").item(0).getTextContent());
                   map.put("base_price1", eElement.getElementsByTagName("base_price1").item(0).getTextContent());         

                   list.add(map);               
              }
        }

        generateCsvFile("C:\\Users\\Master\\Desktop\\demo_jar\\testCSV.csv", list );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void generateCsvFile(String sFilename, List< Map<String, String>>  test) {
    try {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(sFilename);

        writer.append("Address");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("Price1");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("Base_qty1");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("Price2");
        writer.append(",");
        writer.append("base_price1");
        writer.append(",");           
        writer.append(LINE_BREAK);

        for (Map<String, String> map : test) {              

        Iterator iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String,String> mapEntry = (Map.Entry<String,String>) iterator.next();
           //ystem.out.println("key: " + mapEntry.getKey() + ", value:" + mapEntry.getValue());

            writer.append(mapEntry.getValue());
            writer.append(",");
            iterator.remove();
        }
        writer.append(LINE_BREAK);
        }
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
}
```

Comment: How do you verify it is writing another line? Maybe you should use a good editor which you can set up not to insert linebreaks for readability, but only shows the linebreaks in the file.

Comment: can you print a demo string line which crosses the cell boundary

Comment: @Matthias I just check out the output file.If i used any editor then evrrthng is working fine but i want to do it with java only

Comment: @Aanshi Now it is not clear to me what you try to do. I thought you have issues in writing the file. Now you are telling that the output-file is looking fine in an editor. Do you have issues reading the file in java? If yes, then show this code.

Comment: @Matthias yes I m facing problem in writing the file

Comment: @Aanshi How can you have an issue with writing the file if you check what you have written and see that everything is fine?

Comment: @Matthias I think you are not getting my problem.I m saying this is my  code and when i execute this code then if data is too long then it goes to out of while loop and execute this line  writer.append(LINE_BREAK); thats why it shows new line

Answer (score 1):

A .csv is just a text file with commas used to separate the field values - So there is no way you can control the cell sizes that will appear when the file is first opened in Excel.